# Pop up window not opening in windows application when using Azure.Identity InteractiveBrowserCredential class to obtain token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-identity, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Azure.Identity NuGet to access Graph API for Teams. While debugging the popup comes up fine for logging in, but when I run the dll in a process as part of an application, the browser window doesn't open anymore and fails with exception: general exception. This usually happens due to timeout otherwise, but in this case its because there is no browser pop up which in turn is causing the timeout.
I am integrating the code sample they provided here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/tokencredentials.md#1-interactivebrowsercredential
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential?view=azure-dotnet
Does anyone know how I can allow the popups to show for interactive login in wpf integration of MS graph?

Comment: Could you share more information on how your UI application (guess WPF based) is calling the sign in logic implementation in your DLL. Have you tried to use MSAL?

Comment: Hi @AnandSowmithiran, Well, the Rest call uses the system default browser so there is no code handling for this particular code in UI.

Comment: Have you tried to use the approach as described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop#call-the-microsoft-graph-api-by-using-the-token-you-just-obtained)? It uses the MSAL to do authentication(interactively) and then calls a Graph API, you could build on top of it.